# Run all the commands in the code instead of only the first one in Alloy

Tags: alloy

Suppose I have a couple of commands in Alloy, including **run** and **check** commands. When I push the *Execute* button in the IDE, it only executes the first one and ignores the rest.

Is there any way to force Alloy run all the commands in the code one after another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chose `Execute -> Execute All` from the main menu.